Using <aggr>_over_time function returns one more value than expected
Can anyone please help me understand the result I’m seeing with the following query?
Backstory:
I’m currently doing an avg_over_time for the past 365d. This is working great. However, I also would like to get the avg_over_time per month for the past 1 year. Meaning, if I have startTime = Apr 1 2023 and endTime = Mar 31 2024. I would like to get the avg_over_time for each of the months in that range. (The range is always going to start at the start of a month and end at the end of a 365 day)
I see that there are no functions available in VM that denotes month  but instead we have to use 30d (please correct me if there is a way to accomplish this)
Now, to the query part and this is what I have - avg_over_time({__name__=~"label_1", label_2="123", label_3="456"}) or vector (0)&start= 1680321600&end=1711857600&step=30.4d
Note: Using vector (0) to get all the timestamps in the range to figure out missing months in the case of no timeseries and using step = 30.4d to include the end of March.
I expect the number of returned values = 12 since there are 12 months. However, I see that this is returning 13 starting at Apr 1 2023, May 1 2023 and so on until Mar 30 2024.
My question here is: Does the value associated to Apr 1 2023 timestamp signify the avg_over_time for Apr 1 to Apr 30 or is it something different?
Also, please correct me if this approach is wrong

Value associated with timestamp for Apr 1 in query result is average over 30.4 days that end on Apr 1. At least this would be true for Prometheus.

I'm confused because the query has a start = Apr 1 2023 and end = Mar 31 2024. I wonder why would it consider the timeseries that are outside this supplied time range

Maybe this will help: https://www.robustperception.io/step-and-query_range/? Probably last part, about lack of relation between step and range selector is not true for victoria, but general idea is the same.

@markalex Thanks for pointing to the article. The one line I don't understand is that the article says "The provided query is evaluated at the start time, as if using the query endpoint". However, you mentioned that the value associated for Apr 1 2023 in my case would be the result of past 30.4 days that ends on Apr 1 2023 (essentially March 2023) which would fall outside the startTime (Apr 1 2023). Can you please clarify this point?

Query avg_over_time(metric[1d]) evaluated at 12:00 of Apr 1 is calculating average over value from 12:00 of Mar 31 till 12:00 of Apr 1

I understand this for a query type however, I'm still confused as to why it computes timeseries outside the specified start and end time for a query_range

Because time range in query_range request is not related to range selector in query. For what it knows query can not even contain any range selectors. At least this all is about Prometheus. Why the hell VM provides this confusing syntax sugar with ommiting range selectors, allowing this exact confusion to happen is a question to their architects.
